# Publishers issue in ccnet

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I just got a requirement teling me that i should send a
mail to the developers concerned only when i detect errors in the
compilation .If there are no errors ,mail need not be sent to anyone.
So is there any way by which we can configure these things in
ccnet.config file.

With kind regards
Maddy

Answer (score 5):

Maddy, You should be sending emails anytime the "Build" fails, doesn't matter if it is failing at compile, or any tests you have, or whatever. DO NOT LIMIT it to compile. Just because code compiles does not make it right.

Here is the [link](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Email+Publisher) to docs and here is an example

```
<email from="CruiseControlBuild@yourcompany.com" mailhost="yourmailserver.com" includeDetails="True">
            <users />
            <groups>
                <group name="buildmaster" notification="failed"/>
            </groups>
            <converters>
                <regexConverter find="DOMAIN\\" replace="" />
                <regexConverter find="$" replace="@yourcompany.com" />
            </converters>
            <modifierNotificationTypes>
                <NotificationType>Failed</NotificationType>
            </modifierNotificationTypes>
        </email>
```

Comment: Hi alex,Thanks a lot for the effort taken in giving this input.Infact now i got to know the actual problem.When i execute my nant from the command line which invokes my IDE,My IDe executes and there are compilation errors thrown.But the last of execution ,i can see as BUILD SUCCESSFULL instead of BUILD failure.So this doesnt sets the error level and i get successfull all the time.So when this is integrated with my ccnet,i always get BUILD successfull even when compilation errors are present.

Comment: Please note that Alex's snippet is not valid for CCNet 1.5. The group notification has changed. Follow Alex's link to the CCNet site for the newer format.

Answer (score 0):

Only errors in compilation or you mean a failed build in general? A build can fail for a number of reasons, not just because of compilation errors.

For failed builds (and/or other build statuses), there is an [email publisher](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Email+Publisher) you can use.

Comment: I just want to send the email only when i see compilation errors in my IDE.